# How to add “Add guests” details in Google Calendar using Google API Version 2

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, contacts

I am using Google API Version 2 fo .NET to create Google Calendar Entries. How can we set 
"Add guests" in Google Calendar ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try using eventEntry.Participants.Add(new Who(..))